# How to get values from SQLite with the matching ID in Xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, android-sqlite

I'm using Xamarin, and my code is :

```
    DatabaseUpdates updatedb = new DatabaseUpdates();
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ProjectListViewPage);

        updatedb.SetContext(this);

        //db = new ProjectDatabaseFunctions();
        // db.CreatDataBaseProject();
        string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        lstData = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);

        Log.Info("DB_Path", folder);
        LoadData();



        lstData.ItemClick +=  (s, e) =>
        {
            var ID =  lstSource.Where(xc => xc.ID == e.Id).Select(cx => cx.ID);
            FragmentTransaction transation = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            listMenuProject list = new listMenuProject(ID.ToString());
            list.Show(transation, "dialog fragment");
        };

    }
    private void LoadData()
    {
        lstSource = updatedb.selectTableProject();
        var adapter = new ListViewAdapterProject(this, lstSource);
        lstData.Adapter = adapter;
    }
```

This is where I am getting the Id from what is clicked in a list. With this is ID I need to get all the values from that Id and so I edit that data and I also need to make a list with the same list.

The code I have written so far is.

```
 public class DatabaseUpdates
{
    private ProjectDatabase _helper;
    public void SetContext(Context context)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            _helper = new ProjectDatabase(context);
        }

    }
    public bool insertIntoTableProject(Project proj)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(_helper.WritableDatabase.Path))
            {
                connection.Insert(proj);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
    public List<Project> selectTableProject()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(_helper.ReadableDatabase.Path))
            {
                return connection.Table<Project>().ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
    public bool deleteTableProject(int proj)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(_helper.WritableDatabase.Path))
            {
                connection.Delete(proj);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using sqlite-net or sqlite-net-pcl, you can use LINQ to query a table!

Here's something you might use:

```
var project = connection.Table<Project>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == yourId);
```

You can also get a collection by filtering it in the same way:

```
var projects = connection.Table<Project>().Where(p => p.SomeProperty == someValue);
```

Comment: yeah i am using sqlite-net, Thank you :D